# Sublime text indentation Macro

Tags: automation, sublimetext2

I want to create a macro to convert all indentation to tabs using 4 spaces. For that there are 3 command I need to go through each time on each document.

[image]

So I decided to record a Macro, but it doesn't work. I'm guessing macro only works for text. Is there a way to make macro for this?

Comment: You should be able to adapt this: https://gist.github.com/joshmfrankel/5707020

Comment: Also there are automatic tools for this: http://miohtama.github.io/vvv/tools/expandtabs.html